# Evicted pods policy settings in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubelet

I have an AKS. Managed cluster and Microsoft is managing the master. Everything is dandy, except that I am seeing a lot of Evicted pods, from time to time I go and delete these "Evicted pods". How / Where should I set a policy to clean up these Evited pods automatically specifically in Azure AKS.

Answer (score 4):

There is a flag `--terminated-pod-gc-threshold` in Kubernetes controller manager component. But since the cluster is managed by Microsoft you can not modify the flag and set the default value to a lower.

```
--terminated-pod-gc-threshold int32     Default: 12500
Number of terminated pods that can exist before the terminated pod garbage collector starts deleting terminated pods. If <= 0, the terminated pod garbage collector is disabled.
```

So your best bet is to write a script and run it in schedule.

https://gist.github.com/psxvoid/71492191b7cb06260036c90ab30cc9a0

Comment: thank you sadhu. isn't there a way to configure the kubelet on the worker nodes in AKS .script i understand, but i have to login into the worker nodes for this and then set a cronjob. and what if a new nodes are added

Comment: this script uses kubectl which talks to Kubernetes API Server...to run the script you don't need to login to worker nodes